# Angular 2 issue with FlexLayoutModule

Tags: angular, material-design, angular-material, angular-cli, angular-flex-layout

I am trying to use material design in angular 2.
I have imported FlexLayoutModule in app.module.ts as

```
import { FlexLayoutModule } from "@angular/flex-layout";
```

but when I am trying to run the application I get this issue

```
Uncaught Error: Unexpected module 'FlexLayoutModule' declared by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation.
    at syntaxError (compiler.js:485)
    at compiler.js:15290
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (compiler.js:15272)
    at JitCompiler._loadModules (compiler.js:34405)
    at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.js:34366)
    at JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync (compiler.js:34260)
    at CompilerImpl.compileModuleAsync (platform-browser-dynamic.js:239)
    at PlatformRef.bootstrapModule (core.js:5567)
    at Object.184 (main.ts:10)
```

I am not able to get the solution for the same.

Actual use case is to use SlideMenu from material design angular 2

Comment: Would you please show your code for your AppModule?

Comment: What exactly in AppModule?

Comment: All your code in AppModule, so we can see how you imported and registered FlexLayoutModule

Comment: You should add `FlexLayoutModule` to `imports` array not `declarations`

Comment: @yurzuy is correct. All it takes is moving the reference from declarations to imports.